# Compressing BMP methods

Tags: compression, computer-science, image-recognition

I am working on a project to losslessly compress a specific style of BMP images that look like this [image]

I have thought about doing pattern recognition, to find repetitive blocks of N x N pixels but I feel like it wont be fast enough execution time.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have access to the dataset that created these images too, I just use the image to visualize my data.

Answer (score 0):

Optical illusions make it hard to tell for sure but are the colors only black/blue/red/green? If so, the most straightforward compression would be to simply make more efficient use of pixels. I'm thinking pixels use a fixed amount of space regardless of what color they are. Thus, chances are you are using 12x as many pixels as you really need to be. Since a pixel can be a lot more colors than just those four.

A simple way to do that would be to do label the pixels with the following base 4 numbers:

- Black = 0
- Red = 1
- Green = 2
- Blue = 3

Example:

The first four colors of the image seems to be Blue-Red-Blue-Blue. This is equal to 3233 in base 4, which is simply EF in base 16 or 239 in base 10. This is enough to define what the red color of the new pixel should be. The next 4 would define the green color and the final 4 define what the blue color is. Thus turning 12 pixels into a single pixel.

Beyond that you'll probably want to look into more conventional compression software.